# Python mocking not working for shutil.rmtree

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I have a class with a method which uses shutil.rmtree to remove some files if a param is passed as true, How to mock this behavior so as other tests don't break which needs these files.

My class looks like this -

```
class FileConverter(object):

    def __init__(self, path_to_files):
        self._path_to_files = path_to_files

    def convert_files(self, rmv_src=False):
        doStuff()
        if rmv_src:
            shutil.rmtree(self.__path_to_files)

    def doStuff():
        # does some stuff
```

Now my tests look like -

```
class TestFileConverter(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_convert_success(self):
        input_dir = 'resources/files'
        file_converter = FileConverter(input_dir)
        file_converter.convert_files()

        # assert the things from doStuff

    @mock.patch('shutil.rmtree')
    def test_convert_with_rmv(self, rm_mock):
        input_dir = 'resources/files'
        file_converter = FileConverter(input_dir)
        file_converter.convert_files(True)

        self.assertEquals(rm_mock, [call(input_dir)])
```

Now when I run this testsuite the test with rmv gives me assertionError

```
<MagicMock name='rmtree' id='139676276822984'> != [call('resources/images')]
```

and the first test gives me file not found error since the mock did not work and the rmv source test removed the file

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'resources/images'
```

If I comment out the second test with rmv_source true then my first test works fine.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your module has already imported `shutil.rmtree` so mocking it later in the test suite won't do anything.

You need to mock the module when you import `FileConverter`, not afterwards.

```
import sys
from mock import MagicMock

sys.modules['shutil'] = MagicMock()
# and/or
sys.modules['shutil.rmtree'] = MagicMock()
import FileConverter
```

If you still need to use shutil in your test code, then first import it using an alias,and use that when you need the 'real' module:

```
import sys
from mock import MagicMock

import shutil as shutil_orig
sys.modules['shutil'] = MagicMock()
import shutil

print(type(shutil_orig.rmtree))
# <class 'function'>
print(type(shutil.rmtree))
# <class 'mock.mock.MagicMock'>
```

Comment: I use shutil.rmtree in my first test as well to clean up the things generated in the doStuff method, is there a way to mock it only when the second test gets executed that too just for the method call?

Comment: Updated answer to include a solution for this question.

Answer (score 1):

The original post should work except the `call(input_dir)` did not work for me

```
@mock.patch('shutil.rmtree')
def test_convert_with_rmv(self, rm_mock):
    input_dir = 'resources/files'

    rm_mock.return_value = 'REMOVED'
    file_converter = FileConverter(input_dir)
    file_converter.convert_files(True)
    rm_mock.assert_called_with(input_dir)
    self.assertEqual(rm_mock.return_value, 'REMOVED')
```

The `test_convert_with_rmv` has no way removed the `input_dir`, it probably never created in the first place. You could assert this statement in each test before and after `convert_files` called:

```
    self.asserTrue(os.path.isdir(input_dir))
```